# receive as pick branch trigger does not fire

Tags: wcf, workflow-foundation-4

I have a WF4 Service with a flowchart as the root activity. It contains multiple correlated receive activites and decision branching to step through an approval process. The receive activities work perfectly until I try and use one as the trigger for a pick branch.

I am running tracking so can see that the receive is opened and in the persistance I can see the associated bookmark. When I send a client message with the receive type it does not trigger. I have a delay pick branch that fires OK but then the subsequent receive also does not work.

I have checked these receive activities individually and they work OK when not used as the pick trigger. I have tried the pick within a Sequence and a While but no difference.

I cannot see any difference between my implementation and may examples on the web. Am I missing something extra required when the receive is encapsulated by a pick branch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing special about a PickBranch trigger that would cause a receive to behave differently so I suspect it is something with the Receive itself. What kind of errors are you seeing at the client application?

Comment: I'm not getting any errors from the client. It accepts the call but nothing is triggered in the workflow. An identically configured receive works outside of a pick activity.

Comment: Are you using one way messaging, ie a Receive without a SendReply? In that case there is no return message for the client to receive the fault in. In that case add a SendReply so the client can see the error. Also enabling WCF tracing on the service helps track down errors that occur there.

Comment: I have been using one way messaging. To test I put in Receive and SendReply pairs instead and these work. As soon as I remove the SendReply activity the workflow does not respond to the client call.  I guess I can carry on and use the Receive SendReply pairs for now.